# How can I enable arrow buttons in VS Code's scrollbars?

Tags: visual-studio-code

is there a trick to enable scroll arrows in the scrollbars of Visual Studio Code (Version 1.14.2 under Linux-Mint 18.1)
I tried:

```
"editor.scrollbar": {
        "verticalHasArrows": true,
        "horizontalHasArrows": true
}
```

But,
it is first not supported (anymore?) and
second I see the arrows, but have no scrolling action behind them.

Comment: Same on Windows - seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing (v1.84), strangely the options you describe are still there (see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/release/1.84/src/vs/editor/common/config/editorOptions.ts#L2563) and still seem to have partial effect (Ex. the `arrowSize` property), but don't seem to cause arrow buttons to be rendered. I'd consider raising an issue ticket.

See also this related open feature-request issue ticket: [Option to render proper scrollbar #15106](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15106). Give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump". But if you have any design input or use-case that hasn't already been mentioned in the existing comments, you're welcome to make them.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.