# VSCode Scrollbar tips (up and down single line)

Tags: visual-studio-code, scrollbar

Win7 (32 bit) VSCode v1.70.3

I am using VSCode and PlatformIO for ESP8266 development.

When working in the IDE, there is a scrollbar to the right that works as expected.

Unexpected are missing endpoints, the tips or the up and down arrows (left and right on the horizontal scroll bar at the bottom) that allow for scrolling of only one (or a few) lines at a time.

I thought, perhaps, it was just the colors were set such I couldn't see them, but trying to click on the end of the scrollbar did as expected if there were no arrows.

I am new to VSCode and PlatformIO and I am having a hard time figuring out where VSCode stops and PlatformIO starts.

Anyway, I went into settings, searched for scrollbar, and I can change the width or other but no mention of the end tips.

Comment: dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45263508/11107541